So does Lucifer actually have three heads or is this metaphorically speaking?
So does lucifer just have one head but metaphorically has three because of the mockery of the holly spirit...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

this question also seems related: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/why-is-lucifer-three-faced?rq=1
